# Mariadb-bin log grows 100 MB per hour

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Since several days ago the MySQL log is growing at 100 MB per hour rate. I discovered it because my server run out of space and the database crushed. I deleted the logs and everything is OK now except by the fact that the MySQL log is still growing. I've already changed `my.cfn` so now I only keep only 1 day of logs to limit the disk usage.

Any idea of how can I inspect the log file to see what's going on?

Seems that something is not OK with the DB. Besides the situation is severely slowing down the DB response time in my website. Thanks

Comment: The log file should be human-readable, so why not take a look what's in it? Even better: do a `tail -f [logfile]` and watch it grow in real time.

Comment: Unfortunately the file in this binary format: mariadb-bin.000421 is not human-readable. (I've already tried to open it). Thanks!!

Comment: Additional information request, please. Post on pastebin.com or here.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf-ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) complete MySQLTuner report if readily available - 7 or more days uptime is helpful
Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop   OR  top for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
   includes hda & sda (SSD) filesystem type clues 
for server tuning analysis.